# Zend Framework 1: Setting Session Cookie to Http-Only is not working

Tags: zend-framework, session-cookies, php-7.4, cookie-httponly

So, at this very old project where there is still ZF1 running, we tried to put the http-only flag of the session-cookie to TRUE.

We already have this line in the application.ini: `phpSettings.session.cookie_httponly = true`

Then we went to the Session.php of the Framework itself. In line 106, there's the setting for `cookie_httponly`, as seen here: https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Session.php

Instead of `null`, we tried `'On'`, `'on'` and even `true`. We even set a breakpoint in line 205, and it went into the if-block during runtime.

And yet, no matter how many times we delete the session cookie in the browser, there is NO flag shown under HttpOnly when the cookie is created again.

We also have `Zend_Session::setOptions(array('cookie_httponly' => true));` in the code, as seen here in the index.php:

```
[...]
/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

Zend_Session::setOptions(array('cookie_httponly' => true));

$application->bootstrap('frontend')
        ->run();
```

We got no clue what else we should try.

Comment: The cookie will always show in the browser, but if it is HttpOnly, the browser will not allow the cookie to be manipulated in-page (i.e. via JavaScript). There should be a column in the browser inspection UI that shows the HttpOnly status. The only thing that would change is the tru'false flag in that column. Set the flag to true.

Comment: @RobRuchte So isn't it possible to make the cookie have that flag automatically set to true everytime it's generated?

Comment: Hmmm. Try changing the application.ini file to use "phpsettings" - all lowercase - instead of "phpSettings". Zend_Application looks for the ini section in all lowercase, even though the documentation shows camel case. That config is probably being ignored. https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/136735e776f520b081cd374012852cb88cef9a88/library/Zend/Application.php#L153

Comment: Another thing to look at - if you have session.auto_start turned on in your php.ini, you will probably need to set session.cookie_httponly in the php.ini file is well, since PHP will start the session and set the cookie before Zend even gets loaded.

Comment: @RobRuchte Thanks for your help. I tried all these, but after it didn't work neither, I found a method that has been written by an ex-developer where the ```setcookie``` method is used, and where that session cookie is set. I added the missing parameter (httponly) and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I found a method that has been written by some ex-developer, where setcookie is used to create that session cookie. The one parameter named `httponly` was not set (standard value is `false`), after I set it to `true`, it finally worked.

So no matter what I tried (even tried Rob's suggestions, as seen above), it was this one line that had to be editet.

Comment: Hey @DougyDoug, I too have this ZF1 framework I am working with and we are having similar issues to yours. Where can I find the code you are referring to? It would be much appreciated. Thank you.